# Syntax Error on INSERT into User Table in MS Access 2003

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, ms-access-2003

Using VB.NET with ASP.NET and and ms-access 2003 data, I'm trying to input data from a web form to the a table in db.mdb called 'USER'.

I tried this code:

```
 Protected Sub btnCreateAccount_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCreateAccount.Click

    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Brian\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite3\db.mdb;User Id=admin;Password=;")

    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO USER (Name, Surname, Username, Country, TelNo, Password, Address) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", conn)

    If txtPass.Text = txtCPass.Text Then

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = txtName.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Surame", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = txtSurname.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = txtAddress.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Country", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = txtCountry.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = txtUsername.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = txtPass.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@TelNo", OleDbType.Integer).Value = txtTelNo.Text

        Try

            conn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            conn.Close()

        Catch ex As OdbcException
            Throw ex
        Finally
            conn.Close()
            lblAccount.Visible = True


        End Try

    End If

End Sub
```

But it's returning me an error message:

[image]

Any suggestions to why the problem might be cause?

Comment: Strongly suggest you get rid of the `Catch` clause. It messes up your stack trace to make it look like the `Throw Ex` line is the source of the exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`User` and `Password` are reserved keywords. Change the names, or use square brackets around the names in the query:

```
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [USER] (Name, Surname, Username, Country, TelNo, [Password], Address) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", conn)
```

---

Then, for then next error that you will encounter: As the parameters are not named in the query, the parameter objects in the `Parameters` collection has to be added in the same order as they are used in the query.

Comment: Thanks !.. also just one more thing I'm getting an error on `{"Data type mismatch in criteria expression."}` on the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` What might be causing this ?

Comment: @Brian: Have you checked that the parameters is in the correct order? Have you checked that the parameter types correspond to the database types? Have you verified that the phone number only contains digits, so that it's possible to convert to an integer?