# ASP.NET - MS-ACCESS - VB.NET - SQL STATEMENT ERROR

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, ms-access, insert

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this code? It's giving me an error in `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`

```
Protected Sub btnCreateAccount_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCreateAccount.Click

    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Brian\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite3\db.mdb;")

    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [User] (CustomerName, CustomerSurname, Address, Country, TelNo, Username, Password, UserTypeID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", conn)




    If txtPass.Text = txtCPass.Text Then

        conn.Open()


        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerName", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = txtName.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerSurname", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = txtSurname.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = txtAddress.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Country", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = txtCountry.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@TelNo", OleDbType.Integer).Value = txtTelNo.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = txtUsername.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = txtPass.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserTypeID", OleDbType.Integer, 255).Value = "1"





        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        conn.Close()
        lblAccount.Visible = True



    End If

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: It's telling me there's an error in the "INSERT INTO" statement. But I tried it previously, and it was working. All I did was change the column's names in the db and then in asp.net

Comment: Can you run the command by hand. Is there a constraint issue or a column that must be unique.

Comment: There's the 'UserID' which is an autonumber through the ms-access db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: It's probably that `username` and `password` are [reserved keywords in Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852693/syntax-error-on-insert-into-user-table-in-ms-access-2003/9852715#9852715).

Try to surround them with brackets:

```
 ..., TelNo, [Username], [Password], ...
```